# How to display data in select box accoding custom_name?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have created custom module with 2 option(`custom_name, detail_field`).

`custom_name` repeated but `detail_field` is different always.

Now I want to display data in select box. If I select `custom_name`(like: `test`) then all options should be display in dropdown related with custom_name 'test'

For example:

> custom_name:  test1 test2
>
> Detail_field: Test1-1 test1-11 test1-111 test2-1 test2-11 test2-111

I am getting the collection as below:

```
$coll = Mage::getModel('customdetail/detail')->getCollection();
echo '<pre>'; print_r($coll->getData());
```

Comment: what is the output of `print_r($coll->getData());` ???

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [custom_name] => test1
            [custom_detailed] => test1-1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 2
            [custom_name] => test2
            [custom_detailed] => test2-1
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [custom_name] => test1
            [custom_detailed] => test1-11
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4
            [custom_name] => test1
            [custom_detailed] => test1-111
        )
)